# Eigenvalue of an orthogonal projected matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

> Let $P$ be an orthogonal projection onto a subspace $E$ of an inner product space $V$. Dimension of $V$ and $E$ are $n,m$ respectively. Find the eigenvalues of $P$ with their multiplicities.

What I know is as follows:Since $P$ is projection implies $$ P^2=P\implies 0,1\ \text{are the eigen values.}$$ Now how do I compute their multiplicities?

Comment: Hint: Suppose $v\in E$. Then what must $Pv$ be? (Similarly, consider a vector in the orthogonal complement of $E$.)

Comment: Your notation seems to be off; by $r$ do you mean $m$? And $P\perp E$ doesn't make sense; how is a matrix perpendicular to a space? Similarly $\dim(P)$ doesn't make sense; a matrix doesn't have a dimension. Perhaps you mean $\ker P$ in stead of $P$ in both cases?

Comment: Dimension means size.

Comment: In that case, since $P$ is a projection *from* $V$, its size must be $\dim V=n$. But from the implication you wrote, I don't think that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You've made a good start already; you know that the eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$, so the restriction of $P$ to the corresponding eigenspaces $E_0$ and $E_1$ is the zero map and the identity, respectively, i.e.
$$P\vert_{E_0}=0_{E_0}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad P\vert_{E_1}=\operatorname{id}_{E_1}.$$
Can you tell from the 'picture' what $E_0$ and $E_1$ must be? What does that tell you about the multiplicities of the eigenvalues?